# Wix: "Found mismatched entry point <Product> for specified output package type .exe"

Tags: wix

I'm creating a Wix installer and in its properties I set the Output type to "Windows Installer Package (.msi)"

When I do that, the package builds without any problems or warnings. But the package needs to execute a Custom Action after installation, and that needs to run with elevated privileges.

So I decide to change the installer to an Executable. In the Installer tab I change the Output type to "Executable Package (.exe)"

When I build it then, a warning is raised: "Found mismatched entry point . Expected  for specified output package type .exe.   *[name here]*   *[path here]*\obj\x64\Debug\Product.wixobj  0   "

Okay but.... "Product.wixobj" is not one of my source files; it is generated during the build.

So **what do I need to change, and where, in my source files (the .wxs file, perhaps?) to stop it generating a .wixobj file that then leads to this warning**?

Let me apologise straight off the bat here: I don't really know or understand what information you might need to answer this question, so if you need anything, please ask and I will be happy to provide. What I can tell you is that in the .wxs file I set **InstallerVersion** to **500**, **InstallScope** to **perMachine** and the **Platform** to **x64**.

Comment: If you want to have an exe you need an additional bundle project that installs your msi. But it is also possible to start an elevated custom action from the msi installer.

Comment: Ooohhh why didn't I think to ask about that?.... can you give me a little steer on how to start an elevated custom action? Feel free to add that as an answer because it achieves what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an exe installer you would have to create a WIX setup bundle and call your msi there. But you can also run an elevated custom action from your msi.

```
// State that your msi needs to be run elevated.
<Package ... InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>   

// Pass properties to the elevated CA. Property and Id of the elevated CA must match. Can be accessed via CA methods session.CustomActionData dictionary.
<CustomAction Id='ElevatedCA.SetCustomActionData' Property='ElevatedCA' Value='CAPROPERTY=[MSIPROPERTY];'/>
// Define an async deferred custom action
<CustomAction Id='ElevatedCA' BinaryKey='CustomActionsDll' DllEntry='DoMyElevatedStuffMethod'  Return='asyncNoWait'  Impersonate='no' Execute='deferred'/>

// Schedule your custom action
<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='ElevatedCA.SetCustomActionData' Before='ElevatedCA'/>
     <Custom Action='ElevatedCA' After='InstallFinalize'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```